# Are the two shots from the Snap Shot ability on the same game tick?

Tags: runescape

The [Snap Shot](https://runescape.wiki/w/Snap_Shot) ability is a Range ability that fires two shots in one go as seen below:

[image: Snap Shot]

<sub><sub>.Gif from the Wiki page</sub></sub>

However, when using [Soul Split](https://runescape.wiki/w/Soul_Split), only one "soul" is returned back to the player for healing.  This has me wondering - are the two shots from the Snap Shot ability on the same game tick and combined into one soul to heal the player?  Or is only one of the shots counted towards Soul Split?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The animation from soul split is just a visual effect. Soul split returns 10% of damage dealt as health, and it is not tick-based. Here are some pictures:

[image]

This is before I casted snapshot (seen on my ability bar with the shortcut A).

[image]

And this is after. 3648 damage was dealt in the same tick, and my health increased by 354.

While it's not exactly 10%, it's clear that it's not healing you based off one arrow, but both. So, to answer your question, the two shots from the ability are combined into the one soul that heal the player.

Comment: `it's clear that it's not healing you based off one arrow and not both` Might want to rephrase that.

Comment: It's not 10% because hits over 2000 only heal 5%, and hits over 4000 only heal 1.25% [see wiki](http://runescape.wikia.com/wiki/Soul_Split). Anything under 2000 heals 10%.  So, one of your hits was over 2193.  5% of that is 109.65. and 10% of 1455 is 145.5.  Add those to get 255.15.  I'm not sure how you got 354.  Are you wearing an amulet of souls?

Comment: @Flater Oops, fixed

Comment: @TimmyJim No souls equipped, so I'm not sure how I would have received any extra life points. All I had equipped was a bow and arrows

Comment: What is that heart ability on the screen with 78 minutes remaining?

Comment: @TimmyJim Cooldown for the Life Saver [legendary pet ability](http://runescape.wikia.com/wiki/Pet#Abilities)

Comment: I'd like to know what the healing rates are now for soul split, since it seems the wiki may not be correct, but since you answered the question at hand, I've marked it as accepted.

Comment: @TimmyJim Honestly, soul split has always been a little buggy...

Comment: It wouldn't make any sense to reduce the **entire** shot's healing down to 5% if you hit over 2000.  That would mean the optimal strategy would be to always hit 1999.  The healing of *the amount of damage* that is over 2000 is reduced to 5%.  Which means 2000*10% + 193*5% + 1455*10% = 200 + 9.65 + 145.5 = 355.15.  I assume all fractions are truncated to ints which leads to 354